# Range_color attribute seemingly not working in my code that uses plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly-python, plotly-express

I want to fix it from 0 to 200 using the range_color attribute.

The range_color attribute does not do this for some reason, and all the values are within the given range.  I am also then exporting the resultant figure as a png using the kaleido backend, does this maybe override it?
This is the section of code that does this. Each point within the `data` array does not exceed 200 and none are negative.  Why does the range_color attribute not override the scale?

Section of Code that creates the plot and exports it as a png:

`fig = px.choropleth(locationmode='USA-states', locations=location, color=data, scope="usa", range_color=(0,200))`
`fig.write_image("figure.png", engine="kaleido")`

Array example:

```
[4, 2, 0, 8, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 42, 17, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 104, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 21, 0, 36, 8, 4, 8, 0, 10, 0, 0, 7, 47, 0, 0, 0, 29, 21, 1, 0, 0]
```

Result:
[A choropleth map of the USA where the scale does not match the range_color values I put in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAdTn.png)

I have tried it over several differing data sets as well and the scale is never made to be 0 to 200.

Edit:
I just tried recreating the code in a different file and it worked, I did nothing differently except not including some of the code that gets the data from a CSV, instead manually creating the same data set. I'm very confused now.

Comment: I had to flip the values so they were ascending and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

- have created a MWE to define the two arrays that you code snippet depends on
- clearly `range_color` is working as expected.  This points to the fact that your code that sets up these two arrays contains values you do not expect

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# source and structure US states...
df = pd.read_html("https://www.bls.gov/respondents/mwr/electronic-data-interchange/appendix-d-usps-state-abbreviations-and-fips-codes.htm")[0]
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[1:-1, 0:3], df.iloc[1:-1,3:6]]).reset_index(drop=True).iloc[0:-1]

# set up arrays used by sample code
location = df["Postal Abbr."].values
data = np.random.randint(1,300, len(location))

fig = px.choropleth(locationmode='USA-states', locations=location, color=data, scope="usa", range_color=(0,200)) 
# fig.write_image("figure.png", engine="kaleido")
fig
```

[image]